# drop down list default value

Tags: drop-down-menu, default-value

I'm trying to use a drop down list with a default value equals nothing
but nothing means zero and every time i try, it says that i cant divide by zero

how can i make the default value equal null not zero ?

```
<form method="post" action="try.php"name="test">
<select name="xx">
<option selected=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<br /><input type="submit"  name="submit" value="PROSES" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$x=$_POST['xx'];

$z=1/$x;
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to surround the `$z=1/$x;` block with an `if` block, which checks if the value for `x` is set (and maybe also if it is a number) before you use it in a division, because you can neither divide by `null` or by `zero`.